# How to publish Javascript test execution + coverage to SonarQube?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

How can I publish results and coverage of Javascript (Jasmine + Karma) tests in Sonar. Java test execution and coverage are fine. I am trying to add the tests for Javascript executed by Karma (lcov coverageReporter + sonarQubeUnitReporter).

Q1. What Sonar properties (e.g., sources, inclusions, tests, test.inclusion, sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath) should I define?

Q2. In which pom (multi-module pom or submodule pom)?

Q3. To what values must these properties be set?

```
my-multi-modules-project
|-- a_module-project
|   |-- child.pom
|   |-- src/
|   |   |-- main/
|   |   |   |-- java/
|   |   |   |-- javascript/
|   |   |   |   |-- com/mycompany/project/javascript/
|   |   |   |   |   |-- totest.js
|   |   |   |-- resources/
|   |   |-- test/
|   |   |   |-- java/
|   |   |   |-- javascript/
|   |   |   |   |-- com/mycompany/project/javascript/
|   |   |   |   |   |-- specs/
|   |   |   |   |   |   |-- mytest.spec.js
|   |   |   |   | karma.conf.js
|   |   |   |-- package.json
|   |-- target/
|   |   |-- surefire-reports/
|   |   |-- test-results/
|   |   |   |-- lcov.info
|   |   |   |-- sonarQubeUnitReporter.xml
|-- root.pom
|-- target/
```

I want to be reported in Sonar (in addition to already existing Java):

1. Execution of Javascript tests;
2. Coverage for these tests;
3. The link to the Javascript source code (No "Test execution data ignored for n unknown files" message).

Versions:
jasmine 2.99.0
Java 1.8
karma 1.7.1
karma-coverage 1.1.2
Maven 3.5.4
node 7.5
npm 3.0
sonarqube-unit-reporter 0.0.18
SonarQube 7.4

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question.

Refer below code-

`sonar.sources=src/main/javascript
 sonar.tests=src/test/javascript/spec
 sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=test-results/ut_report.xml // for unit tests
 sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=test-results/lcov.info //for coverage`

The path can be relative or absolute depending upon the path of sonar property file location. This should cover your queries. Please refer this https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/ for details of properties.